# How to display incoming h264 stream?

Tags: video, streaming

I have a device streaming out live h264 video using RTSP (TCP).
I can open the video using a PC and VLC player.
To open it, I just need to access `"rtsp://192.168.1.168:554/hdmi"`.

However, now my problem is that, I would like to find a smaller device so I could attach it to the back of my TV which could decode the stream from `"rtsp://192.168.1.168:554/hdmi"`
and record it if needed.

I tried to buy a mini NVR, but it only support protocol like `onvif` and `I8`.
When I plug it into my system, it cannot detect the stream `"rtsp://192.168.1.168:554/hdmi"`.

Any suggestions about what device can I use? Or if there are other small size NVRs that could do the thing?

Comment: what about a Raspberrypi

Comment: Can you give more suggestions? Like what firm ware shall I use for Raspberrypi?